# What's the difference between the script let tag and <script> tag?

Tags: javascript

Most of the functions in *script* tag are not available in scriptlet tag ? Could any explain why the coding in scriptlet tag is different than *script* Tag

Comment: `<scriptlet>` ? what? you mean `<script-let>`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Java is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: The search results for scriptlet include the following: "A scriptlet is a piece of software code that is used by a native Web page scripting language to perform a specific function or process. Scriptlets are primarily implemented in JavaServer Pages (JSP) and include variables, expressions or statements that are used only when requested by a certain client or process."

Comment: Are you using .jsp (Java Server Pages) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"script" is an HTML tag used to include JavaScript on a web page. JavaScript interpreted by the browser Engine (V8 - in Chrome). It runs on client side directly in web browser.

Example:

,

etc..
Example : Login

While ----

"Scriptlet" is a script page construct used to include to run on server like EJS on NodeJS. it is used as <%  %>  as in EJS. EJS scriptlet is executed on the server and needs a server side support platform like Node JS

Example:

## Hi <%= name %>